# What happens when the eip register reaches its maximum value?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu, cpu-registers, eip

The eip register is 32 bits, and it increments for every new instruction. So what happens when it reaches the maximum value for a 32 bit number: 4294967295.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, you don't let it happen. %eip doesn't increment unconditionally; it's affected by flow control instructions (like `jmp`, `call`, `bcc`, etc).

In practice, this behavior is unpredictable. On some CPUs, overflowing %eip causes a fault. On some others, it silently wraps around to zero.

These discrepancies led to a famous exploit of the (original) Xbox boot ROM, as development kits used AMD CPUs (which faulted on wraparound), whereas production hardware used Intel CPUs (which did not). For details, see [*Hacking The Xbox: An Introduction to Reverse Engineering*](http://ia801601.us.archive.org/10/items/HackingTheXbox_Free_Nostarch_2013/HackingTheXbox_Free.pdf), around page 140.